# A recursive sequence $c_n =\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, recurrence-relations

We have a recursive sequence $$c_n =\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}$$ with $n$ square roots.

We can obtain a recursive formula: $$c_n =\sqrt{2+c_{n-1}}\\
c_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+c_n}$$

Now we show that the sequence is increasing:
$$c_{n+1} \geq c_n \rightarrow\text{  This is what we need to prove}$$
$$ 
\sqrt{2+c_n} \geq \sqrt{2+c_{n-1}}\\
2+c_n \geq 2+c_{n-1}\\
c_n \geq c_{n-1} \implies c_{n+1} \geq c_n 
$$
Let's assume that a limit $c$ exists:
$$c = \sqrt{2+c}$$
$$c^2-c-2 = 0 \iff (c-2)(c-1)=0$$
So if the limit exists it is either 2 or 1. We know that it is not 1 since $c_1 > 1$ and the sequence is increasing.
$$c_n \leq 2\\
c_1 \text{ holds}\\$$
Now let's see for $n\rightarrow n+1$:
$$
c_{n+1} \leq 2\\
\sqrt{2+c_{n}} \leq \sqrt{2+2}\leq 2$$
Is the proof that the sequence is increasing  and is bounded sufficient?

Comment: A bounded monotonic sequence converges.

Comment: @saulspatz yes, is the proof that this is such a sequence correct ?

Comment: Yes, everything looks good.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I had some trouble understanding $c_n \geq c_{n-1} \implies c_{n+1} \geq c_n$ in the third paragraph, why is such a statement true, is it really sufficient to just show it like that ?

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient. All the steps are reversible there (assuming you're just working on $\mathbb{R}^+$) so you even get $c_n\ge c_{n-1} \Leftrightarrow c_{n+1}\ge c_n$

Comment: The algebra is all good. But you need to define $c_1$ and $c_2$ to get the recursive definition started. You also need to explain that you are going to prove $c_{n+1} \ge c_n$ by induction and the base case $c_2 \ge c_1$ of the induction (you have just given the algebra for the inductive step).

Comment: Technically I think you should use induction. So all there is to show is that $c_1\geq c_0$ but that should be easy.

Comment: Showing by induction that $c_n=2\,\cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$ might be simpler.

Comment: More than sufficient.  I'd show it is bounded and increasing first and then we don't have to speculate *if* the limit exist as we now a bounded mono incr sequence converges.

Comment: You've factored your quadratic incorrectly.  The two roots are $2$ and $-1$.

Comment: @fleablood How would you show it is bounded and incresing first without doing what I did, how could it be faster ?

Comment: I'd do just what you did.  But I'd speculate on whether a limit exist *after* I showed it was bounded.  If we know it is increasing and bounded then we know the limit exists.  And we don't have to say "IF".

Comment: You know that the supposed limit cannot be $c=1$ _not because_ $c_1 \ge 1$ etc., but rather _because_ $1\ne\sqrt{2+1}$. Simply $c=1$ is not a solution of $c=\sqrt{2+c}$ because it does not satisfy the equation.

Comment: $c^2-c - 2 = (c-2)(c + 1)$ not $(c-2)(c-1)$

Comment: And you never defined $c_0$ and your induction steps have no base cases.

Comment: $c = \pm \sqrt{2+c}$ can have $c=-1$ (not $1$) as a solution. But $\sqrt{2+c_n}$ is presumably positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of growth is presented in a weird backward way. You could write

$$c_{n}\ge c_{n-1}\iff\sqrt{c_{n}+2}\ge\sqrt{c_{n-1}+2}\iff c_{n+1}\ge c_n.$$ You need a base case, which is missing. We indeed have $\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\ge\sqrt2$.

---

You can also condense in a single, non-inductive proof of

$$0\le c_n\le2\implies c_n\le c_{n+1}\le2$$

or equivalently

$$0\le x\le2\implies x\le\sqrt{x+2}\le\sqrt{2+2}$$
because
$$x^2-x-2\le0$$ for $x\in[-1,2]$.

Comment: I see, I will have that in mind in my future proofs. Is it true that that (c-2)(c-1) = 0 is sufficient and I wouldn't have to also show that $c_n \leq 2$ ?

Comment: @BiliDebili: sufficient for what ?

Comment: That after that I could say it is bounded above, without showing $c_n \leq 2$

Comment: Of course $c$ in my case is the suspected limit from as n goes to infinity

Comment: @BiliDebili: not at all. There is no logical connection between $(c-2)(c-1)=0$ (nor even $c=2$) and $c_n\le2$. Think of $c_n=2+1/n$.

Comment: OK so if I got $(c-2)(c-1)$ from $c_{n+1} =\sqrt{2+c_n} $ as n goes to infinity it is $c = \sqrt{2+c} \iff (c-2)(c-1)=0$, then I still have to show $c_n \leq 2$ in any case, if I undersood correctly ?

Comment: @BiliDebili: you have to show convergence.

Comment: @BiliDebili  Dude,  $c^2 - c -2$ does NOT equal $(c-1)(c-2)$.  Until you fix that, you're proof shows only that the limit, if it exists, is either $1$ or $2$.

Comment: @B.Goddard After fixing that, then the proof with modifications from other users would be sufficient right ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the nested radical is infinite we have $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}\Rightarrow x^2-2=x \iff x^2-x-2=0\Rightarrow x=2$

Answer (score 2):

We you define the recursive formula you need to define $c_0 = \sqrt 2$

you don't need to define *both* $c_n$ and $c_{n+1}$.  Defining $c_n = \sqrt{2 + c_{n-1}}$ when $n>1$ is enough.  Or defining $c_{n+1}=\sqrt{2 + c_n}$ is enough.

We can streamline our prove that $c_n$ is increasing and bounded by $2$ in one fell induction step.

$0 \le \sqrt{2} \le c_0 < 2$.

And if $\sqrt {2} \le c_n < 2$ then $c_{n+1} =\sqrt {2 +c_n} > \sqrt {c_n^2 + c_n} > \sqrt{c_n^2} = c_n \ge \sqrt 2$.

And $c_{n+1}= \sqrt{2+c_n} < \sqrt{2 + 2} = 2$.

(Your inductions had no base cases!)

Then as we know it is bounded above and increasing $\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n=c$ exists.

And as $\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} c_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt {2 + c_n} = \sqrt{2 + \lim_{n\to\infty}{c_n}}$ so

$c = \sqrt {2+c} \ge 0$ so

$c^2 - c -2 =0$

$(c-2)(c+1) = 0$ so $c = 2$ or $c = -1$ but $c> 0$ so $c = 2$.